# How to send multiple messages over a socket

Tags: c#, sockets

I saw on the internet how to create a socket server in C#,
after sending to the server one message the server closes.
I have been wondering what can I do to change it so it can handle multiple messages.

The code:

```
static void startServer() {
    Console.WriteLine("[*] Opening server...");
    TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 45784);
    listener.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("[*] Server waiting on port " + 45784);
    TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
    Console.WriteLine("Client connected!");

    StreamReader STR = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
    Console.WriteLine(STR.ReadLine());
}
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string ip = GetIpAdress();
        Console.WriteLine("server on: " + ip);
        startServer();
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: Is the server application exiting?  Normally a server must add a block so the program doesn't exit.  I can't tell what the main() function is doing to see if he server just ends.

Comment: I have a main function that starts this function (I didn't thought it will be necessary).

Comment: please elaborate, do you mean "multiple-lines of message" or "every message from several clients"

Comment: I meant, multiple messages, one after the other from a single client

Comment: The method startServer() will dispose all resources when it returns which will close the server (listerner).  For the code to work you would need to move the definition of listener and client to global space outside of the startServer method() or to loop inside of the startServer function so it doesn't return.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is pretty basic. Simply put your code read only one message and exit.

To read multiple message you just need to put a while loop around this line.

```
Console.WriteLine(STR.ReadLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your server is stopping after receiving one message because that's all you've told it to do (so far).

These lines:

```
StreamReader STR = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
Console.WriteLine(STR.ReadLine());
```

Will handle one message from the client, and then stop since you aren't telling it to grab *another* message.

If you want the server to listen and handle an arbitrary number of messages, you'll want to put this code in a loop.

Try this:

```
static TcpListener StartServer()
{
    Console.WriteLine("[*] Opening server...");
    TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 45784);
    listener.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("[*] Server waiting on port " + 45784);

    return listener;
}

static void Listen(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    string ip = GetIpAddress();
    Console.WriteLine("server on: ");
    var listener = StartServer();

    var client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
    Console.WriteLine("Client connected!");

    var reader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());

    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var cancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    Console.CancelKeyPress += (s, e) =>
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        cancellationSource.Cancel();
    };

    Listen(cancellationSource.Token);
}
```

This code will continue to get lines from the remote client until the server is canceled with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>. It uses a `CancellationToken` to hook into the cancellation event, but you could also use a bool flag if you wanted.

Caveats: This only accepts messages from a **single** client, not multiple clients (that's a different challenge). Also, once the cancel event is sent, the server waits for one more message from the client before exiting and closing the connection, because `ReadLine()` blocks the thread until it sees a message come in.

Answer (score 0):

> I meant, multiple messages, one after the other from a single client.

You need to add some loops.

```
listener.Start();
while(true) {       // beware: please avoid never-ending loop, and define a proper exit condition
    TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
    using(client) {
        Console.WriteLine("Client connected!");

        StreamReader STR = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
        string s = STR.ReadLine();
        while(s != null) { // read until EOF
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
listener.Stop();    // this should always be called after exit condition occurs
```